# How retrieve keyword arguments from a string in python?

Tags: python, string, parsing, format

Let's say, I have a string:

```
  > my_string = '{foo}/{bar}'
  > my_string.format(foo='foo', bar='bar')
  'foo/bar'
```

Right, cool. But in my case, I want to retrieve which are the keywords arguments in `my_string`. I have done:

```
 > ATTRS_PATTERN = re.compile(r'{(?P<variable>[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*)}')
 > ATTRS_PATTERN.findall(my_string)
 ['foo', 'bar']
```

It's not very sexy. Do you have any better idea ?

Comment: Note that format specifiers can be nested one level: `'{hello:{world}}'.format(hello=5.123456, world='.2f') --> 
'5.12'`. If you don't keep track of which fields are used inside other fields you might pass in invalid format specifiers which would raise an error if you ever plan to format the string.

Comment: You don't want to use `parse` ? https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? `string.Formatter` has the [parse()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse) function.

```
>>> import string
>>> [a[1] for a in string.Formatter().parse('{foo}/{bar}')]
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I misunderstood `parse` function

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`string.Formatter.parse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse) method. It splits the string into its literal text components and fields:

```
In [1]: import string

In [2]: formatter = string.Formatter()

In [3]: text = 'Here is some text with {replacement} fields {}'

In [4]: list(formatter.parse(text))
Out[4]: 
[('Here is some text with ', 'replacement', '', None),
 (' fields ', '', '', None)]
```

To retrieve the names fields simply iterate over the result and collect the second field.

Note that this will include positional (both numbered and unnumbered) arguments as well.

Note that this does *not* include *nested* arguments:

```
In [1]: import string

In [2]: formatter = string.Formatter()

In [3]: list(formatter.parse('{hello:{world}}'))
Out[3]: [('', 'hello', '{world}', None)]
```

If you want to get **all** named fields (assuming only named fields are used), you have to parse the second element in the tuple:

```
In [4]: def get_named_fields(text):
   ...:     formatter = string.Formatter()
   ...:     elems = formatter.parse(text)
   ...:     for _, field, spec, _ in elems:
   ...:         if field:
   ...:             yield field
   ...:         if spec:
   ...:             yield from get_named_fields(spec)
   ...:             

In [5]: list(get_named_fields('{hello:{world}}'))
Out[5]: ['hello', 'world']
```

(This solution would allow arbitrarily deep format specifiers, while only one level would be sufficient).

Comment: Nice elegant solution to nested field names