# python string.format, keep unused/overused keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I have template strings with named arguments (for ex. `msg = "{a} {b} {c}"`) and series of functions returning results of some statistical calculations in dictionaries. I want to use these dictionaries to fill templates. However, there is a problem. The exact number of the arguments in the template is not as same as in the dictionary; thus, I can not use simple `msg.format(**result)`. Is there a way to overcome this problem, keeping unused format-blocks for further use?

This is what I have:

```
msg.format(a=1,b=2) -> KeyError: 'c'
```

This is what I want:

```
msg.format(a=1,b=2) -> "1 2 {c}"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python format string unused named arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215400/python-format-string-unused-named-arguments)

Comment: Actually I may have spoken too soon. There is a way to use `.format` in this matter, if you first [get the names of the args of string using `string.Formatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24181068/5858851). Then you can do something like `msg.format(**{**args, **result})` where `args = {x[1]:'{'+x[1]+'}' for x in Formatter().parse(msg)}`. @Jean-François Fabre

Comment: the duplicate looks OK. You may post an answer in the original q

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the difference here is the unpacking of the dict but I defer to your judgement. Will consider posting an answer on one of the originals.

Comment: FYI: posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036131/5858851) on the linked duplicate.