# use .format() in a string in two steps

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I have a string in which I want to replace some variables, but in different steps, something like:

```
my_string = 'text_with_{var_1}_to_variables_{var_2}'
my_string.format(var_1='10')
### make process 1
my_string.format(var_2='22')
```

But when I try to replace the first variable I get an Error:

```
KeyError: 'var_2'
```

How can I accomplish this?

Edit:
I want to create a new list:

```
name = 'Luis'
ids = ['12344','553454','dadada']
def create_list(name,ids):
    my_string = 'text_with_{var_1}_to_variables_{var_2}'.replace('{var_1}',name)
    return [my_string.replace('{var_2}',_id) for _id in ids ]
```

this is the desired output:

```
['text_with_Luis_to_variables_12344',
 'text_with_Luis_to_variables_553454',
 'text_with_Luis_to_variables_dadada']
```

But using .format instead of .replace.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to do here. Are you going to use `my_string` somehow in between those two steps?

Comment: Can you explain what it is you are trying to accomplish exactly? This seems like an [XY](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [partial string formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283961/partial-string-formatting)

Comment: I have added few approaches, that you may find useful

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm thinking in two steps because the second variable is a list. I updated the question.

Comment: @idjaw Interesting link :). Yeah, I could be a XY problem. But I'm curious about using .format() in more than one step.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In simple words, you can not replace few arguments with format `{var_1}`, `var_2` in string(*not all)* using `format`. Even though I am not sure why you want to only replace partial string, but *there are few approaches that you may follow* as a workaround:

**Approach 1:** Replacing the variable you want to replace at second step by `{{}}` instead of `{}`. For example: Replace `{var_2}` by `{{var_2}}`

```
>>> my_string = 'text_with_{var_1}_to_variables_{{var_2}}'
>>> my_string = my_string.format(var_1='VAR_1')
>>> my_string
'text_with_VAR_1_to_variables_{var_2}'
>>> my_string = my_string.format(var_2='VAR_2')
>>> my_string
'text_with_VAR_1_to_variables_VAR_2'
```

**Approach 2:** Replace once using `format` and another using `%`.

```
>>> my_string = 'text_with_{var_1}_to_variables_%(var_2)s'
# Replace first variable
>>> my_string = my_string.format(var_1='VAR_1')
>>> my_string
'text_with_VAR_1_to_variables_%(var_2)s'
# Replace second variable
>>> my_string  = my_string % {'var_2': 'VAR_2'}
>>> my_string
'text_with_VAR_1_to_variables_VAR_2'
```

**Approach 3:** Adding the `args` to a `dict` and unpack it once required.

```
>>> my_string = 'text_with_{var_1}_to_variables_{var_2}'
>>> my_args = {}
# Assign value of `var_1`
>>> my_args['var_1'] = 'VAR_1'
# Assign value of `var_2`
>>> my_args['var_2'] = 'VAR_2'
>>> my_string.format(**my_args)
'text_with_VAR_1_to_variables_VAR_2'
```

Use the one which satisfies your requirement. :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to use format? If not, can you just use string.replace? like

```
my_string = 'text_with_#var_1#_to_variables_#var2#'
my_string = my_string.replace("#var_1#", '10')
###
my_string = my_string.replace("#var2#", '22')
```

Answer (score 0):

following seems to work now.

```
s = 'a {} {{}}'.format('b')
print(s) # prints a b {}
print(s.format('c')) # prints a b c
```