# Escaping curly braces in string to be formatted an undefined number of times

Tags: python, python-2.7, escaping, string-formatting, python-2.x

**Related:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18343661
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466478

You use curly braces ( `{•••}` ) to denote parts of strings to be formatted. If you want to use literal curly brace characters so that they're ignored by `.format()`, you use double curly braces ( `{{•••}}` ). **MCVE:**

```
string = "{format} {{This part won't be formatted. The final string will have literal curly braces here.}}"
print string.format(format='string')
```

If you have a chain of `.format()`s, you double the number of braces for each time you use `.format()`. The last one is surrounded by 4 braces and ends up with literal curly braces in the final output. **MCVE:**

```
string = "{format1} {{format2}} {{{{3rd one won't be formatted. The final string will have literal curly braces here.}}}}"
print string.format(format1='string1').format(format2='string2')
```

It's also possible to format another format string into a format string. The last one is surrounded by 4 braces and ends up with literal curly braces in the final output. **MCVE:**

```
string = "{format1} {{{{3rd one won't be formatted. The final string will have literal curly braces here.}}}}"
print string.format(format1='{format2}').format(format2='string')
```

The problem arises when you use a chain of `.format()`s depending on conditions determined at runtime. If you want a set of the curly braces to be escaped as literal characters, how many do you use? **MCVE:**

```
string = "{} {{{{{{Here I don't know exactly how many curly braces to use because this string is formatted differently due to conditions that I have no control over.}}}}}}"

if fooCondition:
    string = string.format('{} bar')
    if barCondition:
        string = string.format('{} baz')
        if bazCondition:
            string = string.format('{} buzz')
string = string.format('foo')

print string
```

The 1st part of the string has 4 possible outputs:

1. `foo`
2. `foo bar`
3. `foo baz bar`
4. `foo buzz baz bar`

The 2nd part of the string ends up with a different number of curly braces depending on how many conditions are `True`. I want the 2nd part's curly braces to stay permanently escaped, like **not "shed a layer" every time `.format()` is called.** I can solve the problem like this, **MCVE:**

```
string = "{} {{DRY - Don't repeat yourself!}}"

if fooCondition:
    string = string.format('{} bar').replace("{DRY - Don't repeat yourself!}", "{{DRY - Don't repeat yourself!}}")
    if barCondition:
        string = string.format('{} baz').replace("{DRY - Don't repeat yourself!}", "{{DRY - Don't repeat yourself!}}")
        if bazCondition:
            string = string.format('{} buzz').replace("{DRY - Don't repeat yourself!}", "{{DRY - Don't repeat yourself!}}")
string = string.format('foo')

print string
```

[But that's duplicate code (bad practice).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

*The MCVEs aren't my real code. My real code runs on a Google App Engine web server. It's super long and complex. I'm working with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in strings. I want to insert content into the HTML via `.format()` without messing up the curly braces of CSS and JS. My current implementation is un-scalable and very error-prone. I have to manage up to 5 consecutive curly braces (like this: `{{{{{•••}}}}}` ) to pass through `.format()` chains untouched. I need to periodically re-insert curly braces into strings that aren't formatted a fixed number of times. What's an elegant way to fix this spaghetti code?*

**How to PERMANENTLY escape curly braces in Python format string?**

Comment: How does this `.format()` chain work exactly?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't. Perhaps you need to think of another way to handle the task than repeated string `format`ing.

Comment: You PERMANENTLY shouldn't be using string formatting to generate code. Use a proper templating language.

Comment: You could PERMANENTLY provide your relevant code in your question.

Comment: @scharette My relevant code is too long for an MCVE

Comment: Then your question is too broad for SO

Comment: Then I don't see how we can help.

Comment: What is your input and what is expected output? How do you use the `format()` on the string? We cannot help if we don't know the details.

Comment: Why the close votes for too broad? This question is more specific than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo

Comment: Webapp2 has Jinja2 for precisely this use case. Still trying to render code with Python.

Comment: The first answer referenced here comes from the duplicate that I linked. This is a duplicate of that question, in that another technique shown there - implementing `__missing__` for a proxy dict - is the direct and elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put together a partialformat function (in python3.x) that overrides the string format method to allow you to format only those sections of the string that require formatting.  edit: I've included a python 2 version as well.

```
## python 3x version
import string
from _string import formatter_field_name_split
################################################################################
def partialformat(s: str, recursionlimit: int = 10, **kwargs):
    """
    vformat does the acutal work of formatting strings. _vformat is the 
    internal call to vformat and has the ability to alter the recursion 
    limit of how many embedded curly braces to handle. But for some reason 
    vformat does not.  vformat also sets the limit to 2!   

    The 2nd argument of _vformat 'args' allows us to pass in a string which 
    contains an empty curly brace set and ignore them.
    """

    class FormatPlaceholder(object):
        def __init__(self, key):
            self.key = key

        def __format__(self, spec):
            result = self.key
            if spec:
                result += ":" + spec
            return "{" + result + "}"

        def __getitem__(self, item):
            return

    class FormatDict(dict):
        def __missing__(self, key):
            return FormatPlaceholder(key)

    class PartialFormatter(string.Formatter):
        def get_field(self, field_name, args, kwargs):
            try:
                obj, first = super(PartialFormatter, self).get_field(field_name, args, kwargs)
            except (IndexError, KeyError, AttributeError):
                first, rest = formatter_field_name_split(field_name)
                obj = '{' + field_name + '}'

                # loop through the rest of the field_name, doing
                #  getattr or getitem as needed
                for is_attr, i in rest:
                    if is_attr:
                        try:
                            obj = getattr(obj, i)
                        except AttributeError as exc:
                            pass
                    else:
                        obj = obj[i]

            return obj, first

    fmttr = PartialFormatter()
    try:
        fs, _ = fmttr._vformat(s, ("{}",), FormatDict(**kwargs), set(), recursionlimit)
    except Exception as exc:
        raise exc
    return fs
```

edit: looks like python 2.x has some minor differences.

```
## python 2.x version
import string
formatter_field_name_split = str._formatter_field_name_split
def partialformat(s, recursionlimit = 10, **kwargs):
    """
    vformat does the acutal work of formatting strings. _vformat is the 
    internal call to vformat and has the ability to alter the recursion 
    limit of how many embedded curly braces to handle. But for some reason 
    vformat does not.  vformat also sets the limit to 2!   

    The 2nd argument of _vformat 'args' allows us to pass in a string which 
    contains an empty curly brace set and ignore them.
    """

    class FormatPlaceholder(object):
        def __init__(self, key):
            self.key = key

        def __format__(self, spec):
            result = self.key
            if spec:
                result += ":" + spec
            return "{" + result + "}"

        def __getitem__(self, item):
            return

    class FormatDict(dict):
        def __missing__(self, key):
            return FormatPlaceholder(key)

    class PartialFormatter(string.Formatter):
        def get_field(self, field_name, args, kwargs):
            try:
                obj, first = super(PartialFormatter, self).get_field(field_name, args, kwargs)
            except (IndexError, KeyError, AttributeError):
                first, rest = formatter_field_name_split(field_name)
                obj = '{' + field_name + '}'

                # loop through the rest of the field_name, doing
                #  getattr or getitem as needed
                for is_attr, i in rest:
                    if is_attr:
                        try:
                            obj = getattr(obj, i)
                        except AttributeError as exc:
                            pass
                    else:
                        obj = obj[i]

            return obj, first

    fmttr = PartialFormatter()
    try:
        fs = fmttr._vformat(s, ("{}",), FormatDict(**kwargs), set(), recursionlimit)
    except Exception as exc:
        raise exc
    return fs
```

Usage:

```
class ColorObj(object):
    blue = "^BLUE^"
s = '{"a": {"b": {"c": {"d" : {} {foo:<12} & {foo!r} {arg} {color.blue:<10} {color.pink} {blah.atr} }}}}'
print(partialformat(s, foo="Fooolery", arg="ARRrrrrrg!", color=ColorObj))
```

Output:

```
{"a": {"b": {"c": {"d" : {} Fooolery             & 'Fooolery' Fooolery ARRrrrrrg! ^BLUE^ {color.pink} {blah.atr} }}}}
```

Answer (score 5):

The simple and obvious solution is, don't apply `.format()` to a string you don't have complete control over. Instead, perhaps do

```
result = thestring.replace('{postURL}', url).replace('{postTitle}', title)
```

Answer (score 1):

**My solution:**

I substitute "permanent" curly braces in strings with obscure Unicode characters that I'm sure I'll never use for any other purpose.

For instance:

- I type "⁍" to mean "{"
- I type "⁌" to mean "}"

After I've done all my formatting, I replace every substitute character with its corresponding curly brace.

```
stringAfterFormatting.replace("⁍", "{").replace("⁌", "}")
```

Doesn't matter how many times I use chained and nested `.format()`s on strings.

```
string.format(•••).format(•••).format(•••).replace("⁍", "{").replace("⁌", "}")
```

I format what I need to format and `.replace()` the curly braces at the very end.

Comment: Unicode specifically reserves a Private Use Area for stuff like this. You don't have to use a rare character; you can use one which is guaranteed to not be in public use. (Some popular fonts use PUA code points which might thus have "leaked" so maybe google the character codes you want to use before committing to them.)